# Technical term form 'real' (non-test) software system

Tags: terminology, programming

Apologies if this is not the right forum for this question. I'm not an IT person, but I need to describe a 'real' software system, as opposed to its test version. However, I can't seem to find the correct technical term for this – can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yeah, "production" is the usual term.

Comment: You'll get close votes unless you give an example sentence, which would help. Cloud software is often production, prod, or deployed. Shrink wrap or downloadable is released. App store is released or deployed. Test is usually referred to as staged--it could be staged for QA, staged for release/deployment, staged for testing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The usual term is *production software*. See [Wikipedia: Software deployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_deployment).

Answer (score 1):

We call that the *production* system. Other systems used for testing are *pre-production* (which is basically a replica of production, used for final testing), potentially a *beta-test* system, and *alpha*.

Colloquially, the end-user system could be called *live* and releasing software to the production system ("into production") might be to "put it live."